# Mysql insert query issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem with this query, it does not insert for some reason. Is there something wrong with it?

```
<?php       
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {

        $email   = $_POST['email']; 
        $name    = $_POST['name']; 
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];

        if($email && $name ) {

            if($comment) {

                $connect = mysql_connect("dragon.kent.ac.uk", "repo", "3tpyril");

                mysql_select_db("repo");

                $query = mysql_query("INSERT into comments(comment, name,email, newsitemId) VALUES ('$email', '$name','$comment',':newsitemId'=> $_POST[newsitemId])");

                 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Your blog post has been added");</script>';
            } else {

                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please provide some details");</script>';

            }

        } else {

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("All fields required");</script>';

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `':newsitemId'=> $_POST[newsitemId]` This is wrong. try `'newsitemId'=$_POST[newsitemId]`. Also mysql_* functions are deprecated..

Comment: Please reduce your problem so that it involves _one_ language. Not four. Also learn to indent your code.

Comment: You have a syntax error right here: ``':newsitemId'=> $_POST[newsitemId])``. You can also check with ``mysql_error()`` if you have any errors. Anyhow you should switch to MySQLi since these functions are deprecated.

Comment: Looks like you blindly copy/pasted some code from the internet without taking the time to understand what it does.

Comment: Tell us what error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You are trying to use something like prepared statement, but completely wrong way. This should fix it:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT into comments(comment, name,email, newsitemId) VALUES ('$email', '$name','$comment','" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newsitemId']) . "')");
```

To work with prepared statement, you have to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and main idea is to bind variables into query like this:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (:myValue);';
$binds = array(
   'myValue' => $_POST['myValue']
);
$db->Execute($query, $binds);
```

(this is just to point how it works, not example itself)

**EDIT:** In the future, if you will be still using mysql_* functions and your SQL query will looks like broken, use functions [mysql_errno()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php) (to get error code) and [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) (to get error message). It will tell you what is wrong with your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
"INSERT into comments(comment, name,email, newsitemId) VALUES ('$email', '$name','$comment','{$_POST['newsitemId']}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
   $query = mysqli_query("INSERT into comments VALUES ('$email', '$name','$comment', '$_POST[newsitemId]')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this working insert statement but later on as you go and implement your code in the real world you must edited it for security reasons.

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","databasename");

            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
            else
            {
                mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO comments  VALUES ('$email', '$name','$comment', '$_POST[newsitemId]' );
                mysqli_close($con); 
            }
```